Convert numbers to ordinals suffix on google sheet
I'm trying to record some annual data and to look nice I have it so that every time the year ticks up the numbers' suffix goes up too, i.e. 18th, 19th, 20th, etc. The problem is when it goes to 21st it instead says 21th.
I already have it in an IF statement to read the year and add the number up one, but is there a way to nest some IF statements or use another notation so that when the numbers end with 1, 2 or 3 it says 1st, 2nd, and 3rd instead of adding the ths?
I tried
IF((RIGHT(E1, 1)=1), "st", "th")

but that doesn't do anything, maybe because it doesn't make sense.

Add Suffix using Choose()
You may use these two options depending on your preference.
First Option: If you want to put a suffix on a certain range.
=BYROW(TOCOL(F3:F,1),LAMBDA(x,IF(VALUE(RIGHT(FLOOR(x/10),1))=1,x&"th",IFERROR(CHOOSE(RIGHT(x),x&"st",x&"nd",x&"rd"),x&"th"))))

First Output:


Note: Please change the range according to your needs.

Second Option: Based on the cell.
=F3 & CHOOSE(IF(AND(((F3)>3),((F3)<20)),
                    5,
                    MIN(RIGHT((F3),1)+1,5)),
              "th","st","nd","rd","th") & " "

Second Output:


Note: Please change the range according to your needs.

References:

CHOOSE()
IF()
RIGHT()
FLOOR()
LAMBDA FUNCTION
IFERROR
AND
MIN


If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. Feel free to clarify below if this was not the result you want.

You can try:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(a,TOCOL(A:A,1),
   a&IF(ISBETWEEN(a,4,20),"th",
       SWITCH(--RIGHT(a),1,"st",2,"nd",3,"rd","th")))) 


There are rules to creating ordinals. Specifically, if the tenth unit is 1, then th always applies. For eg, 111 is 111th, not 111st. All the previous answers fails in this regard. Here, we calculate the tenth unit using  dividing the number by 10 and getting it's reminder using MOD by dividing again by 10 inside MOD. Once, we have the unit as lambda, we can get 1st unit or 10th unit and then use the base logic for 1st, 2nd and 3rd:
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  LET(
    rg, A1:A15,
    unit, LAMBDA(rg,unit_, ROUNDDOWN(MOD(rg/unit_,10))),
    rg&IF(
     unit(rg,10)=1,"th",
     SWITCH(unit(rg,1), 1, "st", 2, "nd", 3, "rd","th"))))




Numbers
Ordinals




111
111th


121
121st


31
31st


1
1st


5
5th


21
21st


7
7th


8
8th


9
9th


10
10th


11
11th


22
22nd


23
23rd


114
114th


2212
2212th




IF
IF evaluates the condition and if true, returns the output for the TRUE condition, else it outputs the value for the FALSE condition. It only works for 1 condition.
e.g. =IF(some condition, if true do X, else do Y)"
IFS
IFS is a variation on IF, but works through multiple conditions, evaluating each one until a match if found.
If the condition is evaluated to be TRUE, it outputs the value after the comma. If FALSE, it moves to try the next condition.
The last condition can be optionally be added using TRUE as a catch-all for anything not previously matched,to assign a value if nothing else matched.
You can include many conditions. The limit is 127 in Excel, not sure about Google Sheets.
Example:
=IFS(grade>=80,"A",grade>=70,"B",grade>=60,"C",grade>=50,"D",grade>=40,"E",TRUE,"Fail")
A value of 65 doesn't match condition 1, so it tries condition 2 (grade>=70). It doesn't match condition 2 either, so tries condition 3. That evaluates to TRUE so outputs the condition's value, "C".
Assuming the year value is in cell A1, the following IFS formula will work:
=IFS(RIGHT(A1,2)="11","th",RIGHT(A1,2)="12","th",RIGHT(A1,2)="13","th",RIGHT(A1,1)="1","st",RIGHT(A1,1)="2","nd",RIGHT(A1,1)="3","rd",TRUE,"th")

The logic is as follows. It only matches each value once, in the following order:

If the last 2 characters are 11 (e.g. 111) then use "th"
If the last 2 characters are 12 (e.g. 112) then use "th"
If the last 2 characters are 13 (e.g. 113) then use "th"
If the last character is 1 then use "st"
If the last character is 2 then use "nd"
If the last character is 3 then use "rd"
Else use "th"

Result:



value
suffix
built string




2001
st
2001st


2002
nd
2002nd


2003
rd
2003rd


2004
th
2004th


...




2010
th
2010th


2011
th
2011th


2012
th
2012th


2013
th
2013th


2014
th
2014th


...




2020
th
2020th


2021
st
2021st


2022
nd
2022nd


...




2110
th
2110th


2111
th
2111th


2112
th
2112th


2113
th
2113th


2114
th
2114th


2115
th
2115th


...





